# java: does the string .split method change the size of an array

Tags: java, string, split

So I initialized an array lets say

`string example = new string [5];

When I called the split method on a line of

`string x = "abc, def, g";`

`example = x.split(",");`

`example[0] = abc`

`example[1] = def`

`example[2] = g`

I can no longer access example[3] and example[4] as I am getting null pointer

shouldn't these still be accessible with values of null?

Comment: why would you still access `example[3]` and `example[4]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial `example` array (of length 5 with `null` values) gets overwritten by the new array returned by the call to the `split()` method, in this case an array of length 3. The initial array referenced by the `example` reference is not accessible anymore, it will be garbage collected.

If you want to keep both arrays you can assign the result of the split to another variable

```
String[] example2 = x.split(",");
```

Answer (score 3):

Even though you created a array with some initial length for example

```
String [] sample = new String[5];
```

after assigning new Array to the variable It will create a new array with new array size. for example.

```
String s = "Hi how are you";
sample = s.split(" ");
```

so you can not access old array elements.

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt preserve the values. "example" is assigned with a completely new and different array.

If you want to preserve the number of elements previously present in the array, you can do something like:

```
int num = example.length;
example = x.split(",");
example = Arrays.copyOf(example, num);
// initialize the new array elements here.
```

Of course doing so is not very efficent and should be avoided. I suggest you take a look at array lists instead.

Comment: Why should it have to be avoided?

Comment: If you will use it with a small array, and only a few times, its ok. But for intensive use, it will be a resource eater. Besides copying a big array takes cpu. ArrayList is efficient and you can add or remove elements dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, then please let me know if I need to copy and keep a separate array of 10k of Point, what will be the best practice? Copy them one by one, or use this method?

Comment: 10k of data is not much, but it also depends if you will do this many times, for example inside a loop that uses this code repeatedly, or only once every time. Execution time will be longer depending those circumstances. Copying them one by one is slower, using this feature, besides requiring less coding, is also better because it uses some of the core features, which tend to be faster.